# Using Eigen library in vs2012, why it is so slow when run in debug mode？

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I need to debug in debug mode,but it run a long time.
how to accelerate it?

Comment: Mainly because none of the compiler optimizations that Eigen uses are used. To accelerate, run in Release, or make a smaller toy problem.

Comment: You need to enable compiler optimizations even in debug mode, otherwise inlining does not take place and instead of getting, say a single `add` instruction, you'll get dozens of functions calls making it one or two orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: What ggael referred to is often called RelWithDebugInfo in VS.